# Get unmatched rows for foreign key

Tags: mysql, performance, join, foreign-key

Consider two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(128)
) Engine=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE Tags(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  user REFERENCES Users(id),
  tag VARCHAR(128)
) Engine=InnoDB
```

I would like to know which Users do not have any Tags assigned to them. I could do a `LEFT JOIN` and then add a `WHERE` clause for no Tags, but as there are tens of thousands of Users and each could have a few tens of Tags, I think that would be impractical. Is there a better way?

This is running on MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 running in Amazon EC2.

Comment: by the way: inline foreign keys - like `user REFERENCES Users(id)` - are ignored in MySQL. Define them at the end of table definition - with `FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES Users(id)`.

Comment: @ypercube +1 *ad. infinitum*

Comment: @ypercube, just one of those many reasons why you can't rely on MySQL. I created a SQL Fiddle to show that this is indeed broken: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51fc8/1

Comment: @SebastianMeine it probably throws a warning.

Comment: @SebastianMeine: I don't see what the problem that you are referring to is. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dced9/1

Comment: @dotancohen, that comment was directed at ypercube. My SQLFiddle example in there shows that the inline foreign key is indeed ignored. Your SQLFiddle example on the other hand shows that my answer to your original question works. (I will update my answer with a link to it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NOT EXISTS` can help in this case:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dced9/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(Id INT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Tags(Id INT PRIMARY KEY,User INT REFERENCES User(Id));


INSERT INTO Users(Id) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO Users(Id) VALUES(2);


INSERT INTO Tags(Id,User)VALUES(1,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Users AS U WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Tags AS T WHERE T.user = U.id);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dced9/1/0)**:

```
| ID |
|----|
|  2 |
```

(Thanks, @dotancohen for putting this into a SQLFiddle)